# C++ Cash Register Program Not using <string>

Tags: c++, c-strings

I have to write a program without using strings . Here is my code  :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

struct product
{
    char productName[100];
    double productPrice = 0;

};

const int MAX_CHAR = 101;
const int MAX_ITEM = 100;

int main()
{
    product item[MAX_ITEM];
    double total = 0;
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_ITEM; i++)
    {
        cout << "Please , enter the product name(for checkout type -1) : ";
        cin.get(item[i].productName, MAX_CHAR, '\n');
        cin.ignore(100, '\n');

        if (strcmp(item[i].productName, "-1") == 0 ) {
            break;
        }
        else {
            count++;
            cout << "Please , enter the price for " << item[i].productName << " : $";
            cin >> item[i].productPrice;
            cin.ignore(100, '\n');

            total += item[i].productPrice;
            cout << endl << "Product entered : " << item[i].productName << " " << "$" 
                 << fixed << setprecision(2) <<item[i].productPrice << endl;
            cout << "Total : $" << total << endl << endl;
        }

    }

    cout << endl << "###############";
    cout << endl << "Your Receipt : "  << endl << endl;

    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        cout << item[i].productName << " $" << fixed << setprecision(2) << item[i].productPrice << endl;
    }

    cout << endl << "Total : $" << total;
    cout << endl << "###############";

    getchar();
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

I have a couple questions :

1. Why does the program crash if I don't use `cin.ignore(100, '\n');` after `cin >> item[i].productPrice;` ? It's just `cin` without any condition, so it should not leave a new line char in input stream?
2. How can I check if the price doesn't contain incorrect input (so it has only decimal or floating point numbers) ?
3. How can I check if the name contains chars and numbers which are >0 (except -1) ?
4. Is it better to use `cin.getline` in this case ?

Comment: That's not a couple of questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `cin` is an `istream`, so it should leave the newline char in the stream if you use `cin.get()`. I haven't tested if this is the cause of your crash but it sounds like this could give you problems.
2. `char`s are just numbers. A `.` is 46, the digit characters are from 48 through 57. You could read your price input into a buffer and check if you read any char that does not have one of your desired values. If you find an unwanted char, you can decide if you want to repeat the input, ignore this item or exit the program.
3. In your `else` branch, check if the first character of `productName` is a '-'. That way, you already ensured that `productName` is not `-1`.
4. `cin.getline()` discards the newline character, so you could avoid the use of `cin.ignore()`.